# lubridate generates a new NA extra value

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to use a column with dates, but lubridate unexpectedly adds a new extra line, with an *NA* value. I also tried "as.Date" and "as_date", with no good results.

```
cc <- c("Apr 02 2021", 
        "Apr 09 2021", 
        "Apr 16 2021", 
        "Apr 23 2021", 
        "Apr 30 2021")


as.Date(cc,format="%b %d %Y")  
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA

 
lubridate::as_date(cc,format="%b %d %Y")   
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

The next line works, but it causes the problem asked in this question, adding the extra NA value

```
lubridate::mdy(cc,format="%b %d %Y")  
#> Warning: 1 failed to parse.  
#> [1] "2021-04-02" "2021-04-09" "2021-04-16" "2021-04-23" "2021-04-30"  
#> [6] NA
```

I've already restarted R and Rstudio, without any good results. Probably is something simple, but I can't guess what. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: try to use `mdy(cc)`

Comment: Is your system setup in english? For example, mine is in pt-br, where April = Abril, so I also got NA, if I change Apr to Abr it works

Comment: That was fast. @YuriySaraykin that worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ViníciusFélix  My system setup is in Spanish

Comment: @Bert you could also run `Sys.setlocale(locale = "English")` before